# Non-template/route tasks/services

Tags: ember.js

I was wondering what is the best way to implement certain features that don't require templates. IE My application template can have multiple outlets, one of them being a notification service, and it would be constantly checking for new notifications and so on.

However, lets say there is a service for if someone logs into the app from a different browser, it automatically logs you out from the previous one. Basically the ember app would constantly have to be checking for these events to be happening on the server. But what if I had a lot of similar services/tasks that constantly work in the background of the client. How would I implement something like that?

Should it all be in one parent resource/route (maybe the application route), constantly (reloading the model) getting data from the server, waiting for the server to tell the client to log out or what not. Or would it be able to have something like a BackgroundService, that would not be a route, but would basically mimic one by constantly going thru the store to adapter to server to get data.

I know I could simply put a recursive function in the application route's model/aftermodel/beforemodel to be doing this, but I'm not sure if its proper and safe. I also don't know the app would react if this would be a simple ajax call, instead of using ember data. I know ember data does not have to be used, but I'm just wondering how proper/safe this is.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, In the app I'm developing I have also several tasks which just run in the background. I mostly use Ember initializers for this, because you can create as many initializers as you want and separate all background tasks nicely (with the use of an initializer you can even add an order to the tasks in which they need to be started). I'm using ajax requests, but it should also be doable with ember-data. Although this depends off course on what you want to do with the task.

Keep in mind though that when having a lot of background tasks it might slow down your app a bit (because of all the traffic to and from the server). So don't refresh too often.